# How to properly manage fast input with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, input

I am not sure how to properly manage fast input for an input html tag.

Basically I have two checks like this and it generates lots of input events.

Especially when user inputs like 0.045. It gives 5 events.

I would like to get rid of them and send last value 0.045 and send to the database via AJAX.

Have I use some kind of a timer or something? (if it is possible to do of course.)

Thanks!

```
  $(".myCLass").on('change keyup paste', function (event) {
            if (event.which == 45 || event.which == 189) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            UpdateValue(this);
        });

        $(".myCLass").keydown(function (e) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and  ./,
            if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, @Model.NumberDecimalSeparatorHtmlCode]) !== -1 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: home, end, left, right
                (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            UpdateValue(this);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) with [clearTimeout.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearTimeout)

Something like this:

```
var timeoutID;
$(".myCLass").keydown(function(e){
    //do any checks
    //clearTimeout
    if(typeof timeoutID == "number") {
       window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
       delete timeoutID;
    }

    var element = this;
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function (e) {
            UpdateValue(element);
    }, 1000);

});
```

This clears and sets the timeout to one second every keydown. The same thing can be done with your keyup function.

Answer (score 1):

The way to approach this problem is by using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` in such a way that the event will still happen but the ajax does not fire until enough time has passed that you are sure that the user has put in the correct information you want. Here is my approach to accomplish this using your code as an example

```
jQuery(function() {
    $(".myCLass").keydown(function (e) {
        var el = this;
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and  ./,
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, @Model.NumberDecimalSeparatorHtmlCode]) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }//END IF
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }//END IF

        //assuming this is the function used to ajax use a setTimeout
        //if this event has not happened for 2 seconds, execute it
        if (holdEventTO != undefined) {
            clearTimeout(holdEventTO);
        }
        holdEventTO = setTimeout(function() {
            UpdateValue(this);
            delete window.holdEventTO;
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Notice how I check if the variable `holdEventTO` is set before I clear it to prevent errors. I also delete the variable so that the next time the event fires it things it is the first time we use it to ajax. You can change the amount of time of the timeout by replacing my 2000 with another number (note that the number is in thousandths of seconds so 1000 is one second.)